# Inserting values into a Python list

Tags: list, zip

I am attempting to insert items into a list based on the index found in list a.

```
a = [2,1,0]
b = ['c','b','a']
c =[]




for (number,letter) in zip(a,b):

    c.insert(number,[number,letter])


print(c)
```

This outputs: `[[0, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [1, 'b']]`

But I expected: `[[0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c']]`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what actually happens inside your loop.

```
>>> c = []
>>> c.insert(2,[2,'c'])
>>> c
[[2, 'c']]
>>> c.insert(1,[1,'b'])
>>> c
[[2, 'c'], [1, 'b']]
>>> c.insert(0,[0,'a'])
>>> c
[[0, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [1, 'b']]
```

As you can see, the position your values are inserted at is relative to the contents of the list at the time of insertion. I'd recommend just sorting the zipped list.